# Rails/MySql - amount of database connection pool

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the recommended amount of connection pool to a MySql DB on a Rails 2.3.8 application, to my understanding the default is 5, is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to answer that question w/o more information.

What's your expected load? How long does your average DB transaction last? How much data is loaded per query (average)?